# Blank white block in bottom, in footer page

Tags: javascript, html, web

In my page i cant fix white block in bottom, in footer page.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6PZl.png)

Link Page: http://rewardapp.online/index.html

Comment: why is this `<div style="position: absolute;z-index: -10000;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;height: 3994px;"></div>` at the end ? removing it fixes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 3994px;"></div>
```

Delete the above line of code above in the two locations it is written in at the footer of your HTML Document.

The DIV does not have a name, thus cannot be referred to by JavaScript
There is nothing contained inside the DIV element, so it appears to simply be acting as a spacer

the z-index indicates that its to sit at the very background of the elements on the webpage, which tells me that its set to simply be a way to define the page height given it has a height setting of 3994 pixels

It may have been placed in there whilst initially designing your page because other than stretching out the height of the page, it is literally doing nothing.

To find the above line of code
It appears (on output) to be located here (notice there are 2 lines of the same entered)

```
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 3994px;"></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 3994px;"></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</body>
<!-- <body> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the last two div elements on the page. They both have incorrect stylings for the height for what you are trying to achieve. To correct the issue change the height defined within the style attribute of both of these elements to something that suits you. In this case changing them both to 3800px will solve your problem and remove the white space at the bottom of the page.

In attribute to that, neither have any way to reference them which would lead me to believe that they are in fact added to create white space.

You can either resize them or both can be removed from the DOM to remove the whitespace.